# Notepad++ Compare Plugin is not per-character (uses smart highlighting/grouping)

Tags: notepad++

Compare plugin version 2.0.2

[image]

Im trying to compare these decimal numbers(the lon/lat values on the right of each file). As you can see it highlights(in orange) all numbers after the decimal place as "changes" even though the first few numbers are identical. "069" and "525" are the same in both lines, but those characters are highlighted 'changed' anyway. This makes it very hard to see where the numbers differ in a precise manner.

I can't find a setting that would turn this off.

Comment: You could write your own pluggin.

Comment: I found WinMerge and it does what I wanted.